# Refresh form from subform event handler

Tags: ms-access, vba

I seem to be having a problem that looks an awful lot like it could be a bug in MS Access. I have a form which enumerates all the rows in a table and lets you edit them in a subform. Upon clicking save in the subform (standard save button converted to VBA), I want to update the list of records in the main form. I seem to have done just that with this code:

```
Parent!List0.Requery
Parent!List0.Refresh
Parent!List0.SetFocus
```

However, the list of records only seems to update with the changes upon clicking somewhere in the box, giving it focus.

Has anyone run across this, or does anyone have any suggestions as to how to solve this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue, at least not in Access 2010. I had to comment out the `Parent!List0.Refresh` statement because that was causing a run-time error ("Object doesn't support this property or method"), but once I did that the List Box was correctly updated as soon as I clicked the button on the subform. There must be something else at play here. Could you possibly have error handling in place that is "swallowing" the run-time error I received?

Comment: Wow. Quite close. The conversion from embedded macros to VBA created some error handlers (which I didn't notice) and I placed above code accidentally in one of those (at the end of the Sub). Hence, it wasn't executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the issue, at least not in Access 2010. I had to comment out the `Parent!List0.Refresh` statement because that was causing a run-time error ("Object doesn't support this property or method"), but once I did that the List Box was correctly updated as soon as I clicked the button on the subform. There must be something else at play here. Could you possibly have error handling in place that is "swallowing" the run-time error I received?

Set a breakpoint at the beginning of the `Button_Click()` code and follow it through. Perhaps your code is not executing the way you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the Refresh statement, it's not necessary.  You'll probably get a run-time error right there because that property isn't supported.